# Cannot reset Microsoft Outlook file association

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, xml

I accidentally associated *.xml with Microsoft Outlook 2007 (Windows 7 64bits).

I could not reset the association anymore because the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" is greyed out (both from explorer shell and from "Control Panel/Set Associations".

*.xml used to be opened using Notepad++

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.winvistaclub.com/t19.html details the process...if alway use this is grayed out, it may be due to the fact that you are currently associated with that utility already.  that's what it looks like in your screenshot, outlook is already the primary so the box is grayed out.  there is also a regkey to do it.  more discussion of that method is here: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/8a84fcec-22df-4942-8e35-d98dbe96e327

Answer (score 1):

Could just associate the file using the command prompt right?                                                                                                                                                                                assoc           will show you all your file associations. and                   assoc /?        shows you exactly how to do it.

Then theres always just going to......... Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations.

And thats just easiest way there is. There are bunch of other ways but those pretty much easiest.